# Error installing ckeditor: relation "assetables" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ckeditor, paperclip

I am using a ckeditor gem (https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor). I followed the install instructions on readme and all has been working well so far (before generating models for store uploading files). The platform is using:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p448
GEM
...
ckeditor (4.0.11)
climate_control-0.0.3.gem
cocaine-0.5.4.gem
curb-0.8.5.gem
loofah-1.2.1.gem
sax-machine-0.2.1.gem
feedjira-1.2.0.gem
paperclip-4.1.1.gem 
...
```

The error appears after generating models for store uploading files (ActiveRecord + paperclip or ActiveRecord + carrierwave). Before migrating I generated the migration as indicated with "rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=paperclip". As result, all the files were created as should be:

```
create config/initializers/ckeditor.rb
route mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'
create app/models/ckeditor/asset.rb
create app/models/ckeditor/picture.rb
create app/models/ckeditor/attachment_file.rb
create db/migrate/20140504204803_create_ckeditor_assets.rb
```

But... rake db:migrate gives the error message:

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "assetables" does not exist
```

First, I tried to reset the database (development), and then, drop and re-create it, but it didn't work. What I am making wrong?

Please, any feedback is welcome.

Regards,
Carlos

Comment: The rails version is: Rails 3.2.13

Comment: The solution I found is a workaround. First I changed the column name from assetable_id to assetable_idx on the original migration generated by ckeditor. Then I generated another migration changing the column name back from assetable_idx to assetable_id... For my surprise, this worked well without any error on rake db:migrate !!!

Can someone explain us why? It seems to be a bug of ruby 1.9.3 ???

Comment: I have posted my workaround https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/444#issuecomment-50232665 please check